# I closed my background app, and disable GPS for the app, but still get a location notification, Why?

Tags: iphone, background, notifications, location

I am working on an app, which need to track user's location in background. Every 500 meters distance popup a local notification. The problem is sometimes it will show a notification when my app is not running(background). Even if I closed this app, and disable the GPS for this app, It will still popup the notification. Why? It made my user mad. Please give me some advice .Thanks.

Answer (score -1):

Nowadays (recall after iOS4+) **apps continue running at background by default**. If you really wish your app to close down, add this into info.plist:

```
<key>UIApplicationExitsOnSuspend</key>
<true/>
```

Please note that you might have to recheck your app termination code to make sure it works also in this case (save defaults, release notification listeners, close files etc).

Comment: Downvote without a comment? As far as I know, apps still continue running at background, unless you especially force it to exit...